# Switching to work in a branch using EGIT

Tags: git, github, egit

I am pretty new to Git. I am currently using EGIT. I have checked out using the git repo location and I find master with so many branches. Using EGIT I got the master checked-out. Now if i was to work on the branch say branchX, how do I do that in EGIT.

Appreciate your help in this.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Git, but is this really not readily available in the documentation for EGIT? It seems unlikely they'd leave out something quite that fundamental.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: @maba Egit is predominantly used by Java community bro...that's why it has to do more with Java than others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the very useful [EGit Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html) by Lars Vogel:

> Right-click your project and select Team → Branch to create new branches or to switch between existing branches.