# How to change default github branch in eclipse egit from master to main?

Tags: github, eclipse-plugin, egit

Eclipse v4.18 with EGit 5.10 creates new repositories with the default branch name master. Is there a way to change this to the github recommended main branch by default?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650027/changing-the-git-branch-on-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll want to watch for [enhancement 564794](https://bugs.eclipse.org/564794). https://superuser.com/questions/1419613/change-git-init-default-branch-name mentions you can use the `init.defaultBranch` config to affect the `git` cli, and while you can set that config using the Git/Configuration preference page, it does not use the new value.

If you meant to rename the branch in an existing repository, there are different places you can do that in the UI, listed at https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Renaming_an_Existing_Branch

Answer (score 0):

This directly doesn't answer the question but gives an alternative to push local "master" branch to remote "main" branch.

### How to push from local master branch to github main branch in eclipse EGit

In Git perspective, expand the local repo->Remotes->origin

Right click on upstream git URI -> choose 'Configure Push'

click on add under section  Ref mappings/refspec

specify:

- local branch name as master
- remote branch name as main

commit and push to verify.